# Does removing wordpress user delete the related civicrm contact?

Tags: wordpress, 4.7

Does removing a wordpress user delete the related civicrm contact? An admin left the organization so their wordpress login was removed. I now find their civicrm contact in the trash for some reason.

Edit: I just ran another test and the deleted user was still in the list of contacts. So the reason for the deletion of a couple of other contacts/users remains a mystery.

Comment: This is *not* true and never has been.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, this is not an answer for you but as a note to others that the Drupal behaviour is that if you delete the Drupal user the civicrm record is not deleted. (I sometimes wish it would)